# how to create dictionary with comma separated file

Tags: python

Plz suggest how to create dictionary from the following file contetns

```
2,20190327.1.csv.gz
3,20190327.23.csv.gz
4,20190327.21302.csv.gz
2,20190327.24562.csv.gz
```

my required output is

```
{2:20190327.1.csv.gz:982, 3:20190327.23.csv.gz, 4:20190327.21302.csv.gz, 2:20190327.24562.csv.gz}
```

I am new to python and I tried below code but It is not working. Please suggest

```
   from __future__ import print_function
   import csv
   file = '/tmp/.fileA'
      with open(file) as fh:
        rd = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')
        for row in rd:
            print(row)
```

Comment: No, my required output is not list because it has two values, key from 1st field of the file and value from 2nd field of the file.

Comment: A dictionary with the same key (e.g. `2` in your case) will be overwritten with the last value. Is this really what you want?

Comment: In dictionary, the keys are always unique. But in your case, the key '2' repeats twice. Do you want it the other way of key from 2nd field and value from 1st field ?

Comment: i dont want to overwrite, i need these values to compare with another dictonary. can you please suggest an alternate.

Comment: The `DictReader` will return each row as a dictionary, which doesn't sound like what you want. Also, you have the "key" 2 in there twice, so you need a structure that can have the same "key" with different values. Do you want this output as a string?

Comment: Can you show the other "dictionary" you are comparing with? What are you trying to do? Find things in one but not the other? Or that differ?

Comment: got the issue, the way dictonary works. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You could try to make a list of tuples instead, just reading the rows from the file in.

Comment: ok, will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the `DictReader` thinks first row is field mapping, so number 2 will be used as key for next rows. Also, you can't use same key twice, hence one of the situations where 2 is used as key will be overwritten.

```
import csv
file = 'data.csv'

my_dict = {}
with open(file) as fh:
    rd = csv.reader(fh, delimiter=',')
    for row in rd:
        my_dict[row[0]] = row[1]

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
 $ python3 reader.py 
{'2': '20190327.24562.csv.gz', '3': '20190327.23.csv.gz', '4': '20190327.21302.csv.gz'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `defaultdict` from `collections` to handle the unique keys,

The csv file,

```
$ cat some.csv
2,20190327.1.csv.gz
3,20190327.23.csv.gz
4,20190327.21302.csv.gz
2,20190327.24562.csv.gz


$ cat mkdict.py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

import pprint

d = defaultdict(list)
with open('some.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row: # taking care for empty lines :)
            key, value = row
            d[key].append(value)

pprint.pprint(dict(d))
```

And the output,

```
$ python mkdict.py
{'2': ['20190327.1.csv.gz', '20190327.24562.csv.gz'],
 '3': ['20190327.23.csv.gz'],
 '4': ['20190327.21302.csv.gz']}
```